# Replace subfigure indices with new ones

Tags: graphics, subfloats, subcaption

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering  
\subfigure
{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure
{ 
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure[]
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}    
}
\subfigure[]
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure[]
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\subfigure[]
{
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When you generate this code, it prints the indices of the last row, that is (i),(j),(k),(l). I would like them to change to (a), (b), (c), (d)

Comment: Try putting `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}` before the `\subfigure` to be labelled as `(a)`. The manual says that a counter named `subfigure` is used to keep track of subfigure inidces.

Comment: If your final intention is to *group* the pictures into four vertical columns each containing four pictures, this is probably *not* a good idea since changes to image sizes or page geometry will affect the layout and your images will be *misgrouped*. It may be better to put each vertical column of images in a tall box (and give it a sub-caption) and arrange four such tall boxes side by side (and give a main caption).